# Drag and Drop put element on wrong div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm trying to swap two images with [jQuery Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) when user clicks on one element and drags it over another. However, my code does not put images in the correct position. It leaves the destination image in the same place and places the image that was dragged on the next `div`, overlapping another image. Can anybody help me? I'm new on jQuery.

HTML structure:

```
<div class="painel-tabuleiro">
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/1.png"/></div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/2.png"/></div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/3.png"/></div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/4.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/4.png"/></div>
    <div class="containerImg"><img class="elemento" src="imagem/4.png"/></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Relevant jQuery code:

```
$(".elemento").draggable();
$(".containerImg").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var dropped = ui.draggable;
    var droppedOn = event.target;
    $(dropped).css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(droppedOn);
    $(droppedOn.querySelector('img')).css({top: 0,left: 0}).appendTo(dropped.parent());
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a delay before applying the positions because your positions is being overwritten by the plugin.

`$(droppedOn.querySelector('img')).css({top: 0,left: 0})`

Change it to something like this

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(droppedOn).find('img').css({
    top: 0,
    left: 0
  });
}, 10);
```

You can also change `.css()` to `.animate()` to give it an animation.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/f3hvyk0L/2/)